# Cannot install anything, PERL error

Tags: perl, raspberry-pi

I have an raspberry-pi already installed and configured for a local aplication and I need to install other things on. Whatever I try to install, I get the following error:

```
(Can't find string terminator '"' anywhere before EOF at     /usr/share/perl/5.20/warnings.pm line 355.
Compilation failed in require at /usr/share/perl/5.20/Carp.pm line 5.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/share/perl/5.20/Carp.pm line 5.
Compilation failed in require at /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/perl/5.20/IO/File.pm line 8.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/perl/5.20/IO/File.pm line 8.
Compilation failed in require at /usr/share/perl/5.20/FileHandle.pm line 9.
```

It seems that some perl files are corupted or something. I tried reinstalling perl and I also runned

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure perl
sudo apt-get --reinstall install perl-base
```

But I get the same error with string terminator in /usr/share/perl/5.20/warnings.pm line 355. Bellow is the code from warnings.pm at the line 355(the last line from file)

```
Croaker("package '$category' not registered for
NUL NUL NUL NUL NUL
```

and so on. Any help it will be much apreciated. If you need some command outputs just ask. Thanks!

Comment: I am not sure if this is what you are asking for, but Perl already comes with your raspberry pi, have a look at this question: http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/5513/does-raspbian-come-with-perl

Comment: Yes, I know that post, thanks! My system perl is corupted and I cannot reinstall it, upgrade it or build my own version as suggested out there because any of that actions need perl which is corupted. The only valid thing to do is to reinstall the os.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I did to solve the problem and to reinstall the perl and perl-base without reinstalling the os:

I go to /var/cache/apt/archives where I found perl-base_5.20.2-3+deb8u6_armhf.deb and perl_5.20.2-3+deb8u6_armhf.deb then I reinstall them using

```
sudo dpkg -i perl-base_5.20.2-3+deb8u6_armhf.deb
sudo dpkg -i perl_5.20.2-3+deb8u6_armhf.deb
```

Pay attention that your versions can be different. If they are not cached you  can download them from the mirror manually. Hope it will help someone.

Answer (score 1):

sudo apt-get install perl-modules

can help you.

Answer (score 0):

in my case of the same problem it has been necessary:

```
cd /var/cache/apt/archives
sudo dpkg -i perl-base_5.24.1-3+deb9u4_armhf.deb
sudo dpkg -i perl_5.24.1-3+deb9u4_armhf.deb
sudo dpkg -i perl-modules-5.24_5.24.1-3+deb9u4_all.deb
```

Answer (score 0):

What I had to do is to overwrite that file (reinstall did not help me) :

```
cp /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/perl-base/auto/re/re.so /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/perl/5.24.1/auto/re/re.so
```